# change server to client and vice versa socket programming

Tags: android, sockets, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I create an android application that communicates between multiple devices, using socket progamming, that one device is server and other devices are client. But what I need is to change the server while devices communicate with each other. For example at first the device "A" is server, but after a while (due to some calculations or ...) the device "F" become server and device "A" change state to client, without connection disconnected.

Is there any way to do that?

If no, is there any way to connect some android devices with each other and send/receive data among them?

Comment: The question is somewhat meaningless. After you make a connection messages flow bidirectionally. The server-client distinction simply reflects how the connection is initiated.

Comment: @James K Polk . i know that.i want to change server to client and vice versa during the connection.

Comment: Again, there is no distinction between a client and a server after the connection. They are equal peers.